# how to keep jquery ui accordion clicked item highlighted if navigated to other page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

jquery ui accordion is used for navigation in ASP .NET MVC2 site.master page.
Accordion panels contain single line menu items.

If some list item is clicked, new page is loaded but accordion opens first panel.
How to keep current panel opened and clicked item highlighted if new page is opened ?

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
        fillSpace: true, 
        autoHeight: false, 
        navigation: true, 
    collapsible: true 
}); 



<h3> 
    <a href="#">menugroup1</a></h3> 
    <div> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a target='DoklstlG' href='xxxxxx'> 
                item1</a></li> 
            <li><a target='DoklstlO' href='yyyyy'>item2</a></li> 
            <li><a target='UnpaidG' href='zzzzzzz'>item3</a></li> 
            <li>&nbsp;</li> 
... 
        </ul> 
    </div> 

<h3> 
    <a href="#">menugroup2</a></h3> 
<ul> 
    <li><a target='DoklstlVL' href='nnnnnnnn'>menuitem21</a></li> 
    <li><a target='DoklstlSL' href='mmmmmmmmmm'>menuitem22</a></li> 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps!

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var activeIndex = parseInt($('#AccordionIndex').val());

        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: activeIndex,
            event: "mousedown",
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                $('#AccordionIndex').val(index);                   
            }
        });
    });


</script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <input type=hidden id="AccordionIndex" name="AccordionIndex" value=@ViewBag.AccordionIndex />
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />  }
```

When submit is clicked, a controller is set up to receive a [HTTP-POST],
Return that value in your ViewBag.AccordionIndex
example:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult MacSerialCheck(string index, string AccordionIndex) {
if (AccordionIndex == ""){
ViewBag.AccordionIndex="0";
}
else{
ViewBag.AccordionIndex=AccordionIndex;
}
```